# Detecting headphone click and opening an activity on android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem here, I am attempting to create a Google Assistant sort of a thing in that once you press the headset play or pause button it should get picked up by the broadcaster and start a new activity

Here's what I have so far:

Manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".services.MediaButtonReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Broadcast receiver file

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Invisible mode", "Receieved broadcast");
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)){
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if(event== null){
                return;
            }

            int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
            int action = event.getAction();
            long eventtime = event.getEventTime();

            if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE || keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK){
                Log.i("Invisible mode", "Identified media play pause");
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Log.i("Invisible mode", "Found action down");
                    MainActivity.isInvisibleMode = true;
                   Intent main = new Intent();
                   main.setClassName("co.za.ss.mn", "co.za.ss.mn.MainActivity");
                   main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    Log.i("Invisible mode", "Starting main activity in invisible mode");
                   context.startActivity(main);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and in my MainActivity I have a tried adding a few lines to register the receiver

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
        registerReceiver(new MediaButtonReceiver(), intentFilter );
       ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(this, MediaButtonReceiver.class));
```

I get this warning on the logcat instead of the once I placed in my broadcaster

```
Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK, scanCode=226, metaState=0, flags=0xa8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=184566337, downTime=184565800, deviceId=1, source=0x101 }
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong? Whenever I press the headset button nothing happens using my Android 9 device

Comment: Couple of questions: - Are you trying to start MainActivity on receiving the KeyEvent MediaButton Pause/Play? - Are you registering broadcast receiver in MainActivity? - Are you able to get the events when MainActivity is in foreground?

Comment: @SathyaSingaravelu

1 - Yes, I am trying to start mainActivity on receiving the keyEvent MediaButton Pause/Play

2 - Yes, I am registering it there, either the user can open main activity or the headset press

3 - I only get that warning when the activity is in the foreground

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you increase the priority in manifest file to 1000000000000000
2. You can use KeyEventListener to listen for KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE and KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK when your activity is in foreground.